# OptaPlanner: changeMoveSelector

Tags: java, optaplanner

At first I implemented a `SolverConfig.xml` with a `changeMoveSelector` like this:

```
<changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>Project</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>developer</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

After 10 seconds of optimization I got the following result: `-388hard/-65165soft`

After that I uncommented the `changeMoveSelector` and after 10 seconds of optimization I got the following (better!) result: `-350hard/-64713soft`

How does OptaPlanner "moves", when there is no `changeMoveSelector` stated?

Comment: See http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#moveAndNeighborhoodSelection, especially the section about `changeMoveSelector`

Comment: I read it again, but I do not see any hint, why I get a better result without stating a changeMoveSelector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no move selectors are defined, Local Search defaults to a union of change and swap moves - which explains your better result. It's in the docs IIRC.